# How to remove transparent clickable area with canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm working with canvas and I have a question: how to remove clickable area from a transparent image?

For example: I'm using Kinect.JS to make an image and after I make a click event. Ok. But the transparent area from the image it's clickable! I don't want this, because I have images on the back...

Someone can help me?

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Can you post some code and rephrase your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass this parameter when creating the image: **detectionType: "pixel"**

Here is the tutorial explaning.

[Tutorial](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-pixel-detection-with-kineticjs/)

Comment: That requires extra library and the library includes tons of other not related functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a map of points that are not transparent, and then in the click handler check if the click happens at any one of these points.